# Accessing AWS DocumentDB from a separate VPC using VPC Sharing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-documentdb

The [latest DocumentDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html) states that a jump host is necessary for accessing the database from outside its native VPC:

> By design, you access Amazon DocumentDB (with MongoDB compatibility)
>   resources from an Amazon EC2 instance within the same Amazon VPC as
>   the Amazon DocumentDB resources. However, suppose that your use case
>   requires that you or your application access your Amazon DocumentDB
>   resources from outside the cluster's Amazon VPC. In that case, you can
>   use SSH tunneling (also known as "port forwarding") to access your
>   Amazon DocumentDB resources.

However, [VPC sharing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html) seems to allow multiple accounts/VPCs to share the same resources.

**Is it possible to use VPC sharing to access a documentDB resource in another VPC without having to use jump hosts?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/faqs/
Amazon DocumentDB clusters deployed within a VPC can be accessed directly by EC2 instances or other AWS services that are deployed in the same VPC. Additionally, Amazon DocumentDB can be accessed by EC2 instances or other AWS services in different VPCs in the same region or other regions via VPC peering.

We will get the documentation updated.